# Delete a part of variable and assign value to another variable in Shell Script

Tags: shell, sh

I have a shell script variable as follows

```
a='\bin\tem\abc\xyz.sh'
```

I must remove the xyz.sh from the path and need to store it in a another variable called b. That is b must contain '\bin\tem\abc\'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Parameter Expansion:

```
b="${a%\\*}\\"
```

This removes the trailing `\` and everything after it before appending with `\`.

Comment: [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)